# How to disable auto generated config file for project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For each project (with Git enabled), VSCode auto generate a project specific config file called `.vscode`.

How to disable this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some extention is doing it? It shouldn't create folder unless workspace settings were changed or created runner or tasks or debug.

- Look what's inside that settings.json file.
- Try to run vscode without extentions.

You can also exclude it from explorer:

setting.json (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) >>

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.vscode": true,
},
```